# Compiling plugin for QGIS with pb_tool or Makefile, in windows?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8

I created my pluging with pluging builder, after compile the resources file, i test my pluging in QGIS 2.8.2. I modify the ui file in QtDesigner, but i don't know how to compile it in order to see the changes that i made in the ui file.

Can you help me?

Comment: I downloaded the pb_tool.tar

Comment: The method I used to compile custom-made plugins in Windows was to load the **OSGeo4W Shell** program, type `cd your_plugin_path`, press enter and then type `make`. Hope it works for you too!

Comment: Okey thank you joseph, i'm going to try this method

Comment: Hi Joseph, when i go to pluging path and type make, it doesn't work. I have as message (make: Nothing to be done for 'default' )

Comment: That message could mean that your plugin has already been compiled. Have you reloaded QGIS to see if your plugin has been updated or was QGIS closed when you edited your plugin (not sure if this makes any difference but I do this to be sure)?

Comment: Yesssssss, now it's work. Thank you so much Joseph

Comment: Awesome! Glad it works buddy :) Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Comment: You will post it?

Comment: You can post it, can gain you some reputation :)

Answer (score 3):

The user **Joseph** help me to solve the problem. I'm so happy to share with you the steps:

1. Open QGis 2.8.2
2. Create your plugin with plugin builder. Click ok when you finished filling the form.
3. Select the plugin folder (C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins) where your plugin will be saved.
4. The pluging builder result appear, and then press Ok.
5. Go to the command prompt of OSGeo4w and type :

`cd  C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\your_plugins`

6. Type **make** then **press enter**
7. Close and open Qgis 2.8.2, go to the menu: *Plugins>Manage and install plugins*. Choose your plugin in the list.
8. To modify the form : open Qt4Designer, go to the menu and open the ui file: `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\yourPlugins_Dialog_base.ui`
9. Modify the form, put other controls and save
10. Go to QGis 2.8.2, reload the plugin
11. Click on your plugin in order to see the change that you made on the form.

Comment: I had an issue after upgrading to QGIS 3.4.   pb_tool would return "subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.4\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts\\pyrcc5.BAT', '-o', 'resources.py', 'resources.qrc']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS C:\Users\Cary\Documents\Programming\Python\QGIS\structuremanager>"   I had to uninstall pyqt5 and reinstall.   The problem was fixed.